# why is hibernate automatically picking .hbm.xml files

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In a project I converted from native Hibernate to JPA, it seems Hibernate is picking .hbm.xml for individual entities automatically.

While migrating to JPA, I didn't add any persistence annotation for now, keeping legacy .hbm.xml files per entity + a general hibernate-myappname.cfg.xml listing all of them. I then noticed that Hibernate (in a Wildfly container) was complaining that I had some duplicated queries that were defined in some .hbm.xml files. So, it seems Hibernate picks them up automatically for some reason, although I couldn't find anything in any documentation.

OTA, some mapping files from other JARs aren't being picked up.

Is there a setting to control that behavior?

EDIT: here is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="singleEnginePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/SeXADataSource</jta-data-source>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate-singleengine.cfg.xml" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: add the cfg.xml and the sessionFactory config

Comment: @MaciejKowalski It's JPA, so I don't have any. I added my persistence.xml

Comment: you mentioned that you kept your legay hibernate config files.. is the hibernate.cfg.xml still somewehere on the classpath?

Comment: Yes (with above name, not the default one), but it's only picked up when I mention it in persistence.xml. The .hbm.xml files from the same jar are picked up automatically.